# Find a value of a key by another key's value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I'm willing to find a value of a specific key in case another key's value is X.

My array has several other arrays with the following structure:

```
 [3] => Array
        (
            [ŠIFRA VALUTE] => 156
            [NAZIV ZEMLJE] => Kina
            [OZNAKA VALUTE] => CNY
            [VAŽI ZA] => 1
            [SREDNJI KURS] => 16.8711
        )
```

I'm willing to find in the main array, all the values of SREDNJI KURS only if the value of OZNAKA VALUTE is "CNY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood from your question:

```
var_dump($data);
/*
     [0] => Array
            (
                [ŠIFRA VALUTE] => 156
                [NAZIV ZEMLJE] => Kina
                [OZNAKA VALUTE] => CNY
                [VAŽI ZA] => 1
                [SREDNJI KURS] => 16.8711
            ),
     [1] => Array
            (
                [ŠIFRA VALUTE] => 156
                [NAZIV ZEMLJE] => Kina
                [OZNAKA VALUTE] => CNY
                [VAŽI ZA] => 1
                [SREDNJI KURS] => 16.8711
            )*/
```

Just use a simple loop over the array and check where the value of that specific key is CNY.

```
foreach($data as $row){
  if($row['OZNAKA VALUTE'] == "CNY"){
    echo $row['SREDNJI KURS'];
    //or save it in an array or whatever you'd like to do with it.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I was looking for but I really didn't know how to write a question properly...

Comment: In order to help other to help you - work on your phrasing/writing questions. Even by simple examples of "what I have (input)" and "what I want (output)". In case it helped, please approve my answer.

Comment: I already did, but it says i need to wait 7  minutes. Can you please edit my question because of those people who LOVE to downvote it, thanks.
I am in a lack of proper words